# If $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, for $\alpha$ an algebraic integer, is $x^{-1} N(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ too?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic integer. Assume $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}$ to avoid triviality. So the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has the form 
$$m(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \geq 2$. Since $p$ is irreducible, we know that its roots, $\alpha_1 = \alpha,\alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n$ are distinct. Recall the the field norm on $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is given by 
$$N(z)  =\prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(z)$$
where $\sigma_i$ is the isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \to \mathbb{Q}[\alpha_i]$ sending $\alpha \mapsto \alpha_i$. Alternatively, one can  check that $N(z)$ equals the determinant of the linear transformation $y \mapsto zy : \mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \to \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is viewed as an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. This second picture is rather useful as it implies $N(z) \in \mathbb{Z}$ whenever $z \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, basically because with respect to the obvious basis $1,\alpha,\ldots, \alpha^{n-1}$, the transformation $y \mapsto zy$ has integer entries.

OK so much for background. The question which is bothering me is the following:

> **Question:** Suppose that $z \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $z \neq 0$. Let us define 
>   $$\widetilde{z} := N(z)z^{-1} = \sigma_2(z) \cdots \sigma_n(z)$$ 
>   so that $\widetilde{z}z = N(z)$ is satisfied. Obviously 
>   $\widetilde{z} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. I would like to know: if $z \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, is it also true that $\widetilde{z} \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

In the special case where $\alpha$ is quadratic, so $p(x) = x^2 -tx + \delta = (x- \alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$, this is true because $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = t$, showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1] = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha_2]$. Thus, $\widetilde{z} = \sigma_2(z)$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ if $z$ does.

I also checked this is true in the the case $\alpha = 2^{1/3}$. I found that if 
$$z = a + b \alpha + c \alpha^2$$
then
$$\widetilde{z} = (a^2 - 2bc) + (2c^2 - ba) \alpha + (b^2 - ac) \alpha^2$$
which shows $\widetilde{z}$ belongs to  $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ if $z$ does.

Comment: If anybody can think of a more descriptive/useful title for this question, please don't hesitate to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is always true.

Because $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer and $z\in\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$, we can conclude that $z$ is an algebraic integer as well.

Consider the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $z$,
$$
m(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in\Bbb{Z}[x].
$$
We have $m(z)=0$, so $(x-z)\mid m(x)$ in the ring $R[x]$, $R=\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$. Because $x-z$ is monic, the (long) polynomial division works in $R[x]$, and we get that
$$
m(x)=(x-z)q(x)
$$
for some polynomial $q(x)\in R[x]$.

Your claim follows because the constant term $\pm N(z)z^{-1}$ of $q(x)$  is an element of $R$.

Comment: Polynomial division algorithm works over any commutative ring as long as you are dividing by a monic polynomial.

Comment: This sounds great! And, conveniently, I discovered that fact about dividing by monic polynomials a couple days ago. Certainly I see this implies my claim for the element $\alpha$... let me think to see why it does the job for general elements.

Comment: @MikeF Sorry, I missed that part of the question. If $z\in\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$, then $z$ is an algebraic integer itself, and the same argument shows that $N(z)z^{-1}\in\Bbb{Z}[z]\subseteq \Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: Hmmm but doesn't the $N$ in your above comment conflate "$N_z$" with "$N_\alpha$", or do I misunderstand you...?

Comment: Sorry about not making it clear (mod duties elsewhere). Does it look clear now?

Comment: I'm still a little confused. The last sentence of your answer seems to suggest you are assuming the constant term of $m(x)$ is $\pm N(z)$. But this isn't necessarily true, right? Stupid example: if $\alpha$ is cubic then $N(k) = \sigma_1(k) \sigma_2(k) \sigma_3(k) = k^3$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, even though $m(x) = x-k$.

Comment: Ahh! A good point @MikeF Rethink (when I find the time).

Comment: I think that, in order to finish off the argument for general $z \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, we can do exactly what you suggest except use simply "$g(x) = N(x-z)$" or, more precisely, $g(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x - \sigma_i(z))$ where you used the minimum polynomial $m(x)$ of $z$. This way, the constant term of $g(x)$ really is $\pm N(z)$. And we clearly have $g(z) = 0$.

Comment: On the other hand, now an argument is needed in order to claim $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. I think it should actually be true that $g(x)  = m(x)^k$, where $k=[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}[z]]$, by using some facts about isomorphism extension. Does this seem correct to you?